# Using Case When on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I am trying to get the **specific value of row** with that refer from the **ID**, and give it a result as **selected** from these **column of row**.

For example, I have a table like this:

| member_id | member_number | member_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1511 | 99084213654 | CarMember |
| 1511 | 4435654121 | TaxiMember |
| 1511 | AA11133 | BusMember |
| 6612 | 97970897131 | CarMember |
| 6612 | AA23564 | BusMember |

I need to **convert** it into a **table** like this:

| member_id | CarMember | TaxiMember |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1511 | 99084213654 | 4435654121 |
| 6612 | 97970897131 | NULL |

I have trying using a **script** like this, but didn't help

```sql
with stg_1 as (
    select member_id,
    CASE WHEN member_type = 'CarMember' THEN member_number END AS CarMember,
    CASE WHEN member_type = 'TaxiMember' THEN member_number END AS TaxiMember
    FROM source_member
)
select * FROM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only missed the aggregation part in your attempt.
Try the following:

```
;with stg_1 as (
    select member_id,
    max(CASE WHEN member_type = 'CarMember' THEN member_number END) AS CarMember,
    max(CASE WHEN member_type = 'TaxiMember' THEN member_number END) AS TaxiMember
    FROM source_member
    group by member_id
)
select * FROM stg_1
```

Please see the db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=144e41b0b8e9d1b4f0e318467414bc52).

Comment: I just want to ask, why MAX aggregation is needed to do this task?

Comment: @madfrostx just to summarise all the results to one row for a member_id, otherwise you'll get multiple rows for the same id, and max is useful to pick the non-null value. You must have to group the ids to get the results into a single row.

Comment: @madfrostx you can see in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2ac4102c24c8051d3074d6b1bd692d8) example clearly that why aggregation is required to get the desired result.

Comment: Uhm sorry, how about if there are any duplicates on the row for example on `member_type` column? is it I only need to add the `member_type` column on `group by` ? [This is what I mean from the example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd0e50639decefdf3f00b1db9bd268d0)

Comment: @madfrostx You need to study and learn the concept of grouping and aggregates. If you have multiple rows for a given member ID and type, which value do you want to appear in the **single row** you seem to desire? And since your data is more complicated then you posted, update your post with that information. Don't bury it in a comment. Perhaps this is a "first in group" situation (a term you can search)?

Comment: @madfrostx No, in that case, your whole question would be different as you would possibly require multiple columns (TaxiMember1, TaxiMember2 etc.) for a member_id rather than simply pivoting a single value for a member_id or you could select any one of the values for a type (using simple aggregation). For a smaller number of "types", you could use something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a33e3c6f3ae8976fc2c20ba052e652bf) if all the values need to be pivoted.

Answer (score 2):

CTE is not needed here. Just use aggregate function for retrieving desired result.

```
-- SQL Server (v2017)
SELECT member_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN member_type = 'CarMember' THEN member_number END) CarMember
     , MAX(CASE WHEN member_type = 'TaxiMember' THEN member_number END) TaxiMember
FROM source_member
GROUP BY member_id
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2d71716a4c7b04f48062892b49429d9d

Comment: Welcome @madfrostx. In above example MAX() is used for eliminating NULL values. Because for id = 1511 two rows exist in table one is car and other is taxi. Without MAX() you'll get two rows for a member like this first row 1511, value for car, NULL for taxi and 2nd row 1511, NULL for car, value for taxi